# nodejs crawler response.body vs response conversion to jquery?

Tags: node.js, parsing, web-crawler, cheerio

i use [crawler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crawler) how is a builtin cheerio crawler inside my nodejs project.

my crawler start with a function like this (and like exemple in doc) :

```
let c = new Crawler({
maxConnections: 10,


callback: (error, res, done) => {
    if (error) { throw err; } else {
        let $ = res.$;

        

        let content_test1 = $("*").toString();
        let content_test2 = res.body;

        let file_test1 = fs.writeFile(path, content_test1, (err) => {
            err ? console.log(err) : console.log("done");
        });
        let file_test2 = fs.writeFile(path, content_test2, (err) => {
            err ? console.log(err) : console.log("done");
        });
    }
    done();
}});
let browser = c.queue('https://someUrl.com');
```

problem is "content_test1" file is 4x more larger than file created with "content_test2" as data, and most of html seems to be duplicated. so where i'm wrong ?

regards.

Charly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$("*")` selects *all* elements in the document. That includes the nested ones. Here

```html
<div>Outer <div>Middle <div>Inner</div></div></div>
```

it will select

```html
<div>Outer <div>Middle <div>Inner</div></div></div>
<div>Middle <div>Inner</div></div>
<div>Inner</div>
```